# In Sinatra, how do i pass control to a named route?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

From there docs i see that `pass` will automatically determine the route the control will be passed to.

How can i pass control to a named route?

This does not work for me:

```
get '/:title.:ext' do
  pass "/old/#{params[:title]}" if params[:ext] == 'php'
  # more logic
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [`redirect`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Browser%20Redirect), if you actually want the URL in the user's browser to change, or use [`call!`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Triggering%20Another%20Route) directly if you want the forwarding to be hidden from the end user (i.e. the URL in their browser stays the same, but internally the request is forwarded to a different route in your application).

So in your case, it would either be

```
redirect "/old/#{params[:title]}" if params[:ext] == 'php'
```

or

```
call! env.merge('PATH_INFO' => "/old/#{params[:title]}") if params[:ext] == 'php'
```

Comment: Make a helper method for it, if you want.